# Get .NET Core Worker Service CommandLineConfigurationProvider Arguments

Tags: .net-core

I creating a .NET Core Worker Service app and need to get the Command-Line arguments passed into the app.  I can see the arguments while debugging via the IConfiguration configuration > Providers > CommandLineConfigurationProvider, but don't know how to code it to get the arguments.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

If you have an object `config` that provides `IConfiguration` you simply use `config.GetValue<string>("myvaluename"`).

For example:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.AddCommandLine(args);
        });
}
```

To get the config:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
    var config = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
    var myvalue = config.GetValue<string>("myvalue");
    // .... myvalue may be null if not specified
}
```

Finally, you invoke your program like this:

```
myprogram.exe --myvalue abcd
```

The `CommandLineConfigurationProvider` is pretty basic, so it doesn't support complex patterns like binary options (present/not present), etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?view=netcore-3.1

To get the command line arguments.

Environment is static so you can access this from anywhere.

```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs
```

Comment: This appears to work.  When using this in debug mode, you have to skip the first element as it seems to pass in the DLL path.  I was thinking there was another way.  I'm using your suggestion for now.  Thank you.

Comment: @Shaggy great. Is your question satisfied now? if so please mark the answer as completed - if not what are you missing?